# font size affecting size of Label

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

As far as I know, changing the Font size of a System.Windows.Forms.Label doesn't affect (effect?) it's size. However, in my case it seems it does. What I want in the following code example is a Label that fills the screen. I do that by placing it in a TableLayoutPanel and make both have DockStyle.Fill. I made the Label red for visibility.

Now I start messing around with the font-size on each resize. If I set the font-size to a specific value, everything works as expected. However if I set the Font-size to something dynamic, however simplistic, I get that the size of the Label resets to the initial size of (100, 23) and stays at that size. Why does this happen?

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        //Create a TableLayoutPanel that covers the entire screen with 1 cell.
        TableLayoutPanel TLP = new TableLayoutPanel();
        TLP.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        TLP.RowCount = 1;
        TLP.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 1F));
        TLP.ColumnCount = 1;
        TLP.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 1F));

        //Create a Label that fills the entire cell of the TableLayoutPanel. Make the Label red to visualise it's size.
        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        label1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        label1.Resize += new EventHandler((o,e) => Form2.test((Label)o));
        TLP.Controls.Add(label1, 0, 0);

        //Add the TableLayoutPanel to the controls
        this.Controls.Add(TLP);
    }

    //Methode that messes around with the font-size a bit.
    public static void test(Label label1)
    {
        if (label1.Font.Size == 3)
        {
            label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, 4F);
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, 3F);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

This problem came up when I wanted to dynamicly set the font-size of a Label in such a way that the text always filled the size of the Label as good as possible.

Comment: How do you resize the label?

Comment: Well, the TableLayoutPanel should be resizing the Label. I am not resizing the Label manually. Remove the line that adds the EventHandler to label1.resize to see the Label filling the screen.

Comment: The problem is in the test sub. It loops from 3 to 4 to 3 ... If you remove `label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.FontFamily, 4F);` the font doesnt affect the label size.

Comment: Layout calculation order is often an issue.  You really should avoid creating conflicts, set the label's AutoSize property to *false*.

Comment: @valter: yes, setting the font to a constant value is a way to resolve the problem. However I want to set the font dynamicly. This example is a bit silly, but I wanted to demonstrate the problem as simple as possible.

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't understand your post. Setting the AutoSize property of label1 to false when I initialise label1 didn't resolve the problem. How do I avoid these kinds of conflicts? Is there a better way to resize the font to make sure the text always fills the label?

Comment: The size of the font wont affect the size of the label. The worst it can happen is the text wont fit inside. The problem is when you have an infinite loop, like in your test sub. The system resolves to the default size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Font f;
        Graphics g;
        SizeF s;
        Single Faktor, FaktorX, FaktorY;

        g = label2.CreateGraphics();
        s = g.MeasureString(label2.Text, label2.Font, label2.Size);
        g.Dispose();

        FaktorX = label2.Width / s.Width;
        FaktorY = label2.Height / s.Height;

        if (FaktorX > FaktorY)
        {
            Faktor = FaktorY;
        }
        else
        {
            Faktor = FaktorX;
        }

        f = label2.Font;
        label2.Font = new Font(f.Name, f.SizeInPoints * Faktor);
    }
```

It is not pretty but you can work on this

valter

Comment: There might be an exception concerning the minimum size of a font. Just check if `f.SizeInPoints * Faktor` is greater than 1.

Comment: @MenelaosVergis Ellin? Nice! I know it is not perfect. He can use it as a start point.

Comment: Yes :) I have created a solution like this in [Chordastic](http://www.chordastic.com) and it is working fine. Well you cannot find the size of the text without rendering it on a `Graphic` object.

Comment: @valter: Ah, so just resize the label on the resize event of the Panel. I'll try that.